# What is the max number mt_rand() can generate in windows?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Actually in my php application i want to assign every user a unique number code. For that i am using mt_rand(0,100000000). I want it to generate millions of number for say millions of different users without repeats and save it to database. Is it possible ? Or any other technique is recommended ? 
Also to make sure the number doesn't repeat I am checking if the number already exists in the db through php, if it does exist i reload the page to generate another number and save it to db orelse continue to save the number as it is.
Is it the best pratice ?

I am new to this non repeating number generator in php so don't know the efficient method.

Comment: you need to get in the habit of accepting answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mt_getrandmax()` to get the biggest value for `mt_rand()`.

Just as the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) says,

> max: Optional highest value to be returned (default: mt_getrandmax())
>
> min max range must be within the range mt_getrandmax(). i.e. (max - min) <= mt_getrandmax() *Otherwise, mt_rand() may return poorer random numbers than it should.*